# JavaScript, images, and css do not load in Firefox over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, https

This is one of those issues where I'm going to punch myself in the face for not figuring out, but here goes anyway.

I've got a simple Laravel app (Laravel really has nothing to do with this anyway) and I need it to load its assets. The problem is, nothing loads. If you view page source and click on one of the links to the asset, it loads fine. If you view the network panel in firebug, no requests are even made for the files. That's 0 requests being made for the files.

I should mention, though, that this only happens in firefox. An item of note is that this page is served over HTTPS via self signed certificate (it's on a dev machine). Chrome and Safari both load the assets fine.

Let me know if you need any more information and I'll be happy to provide.

Here are some screens
[image: lack of styling]
[image: no requests are even made]

Comment: I wonder what HTML exactly does `{{ asset }}` generate, what HTML do you see in Firefox?

Comment: asset() doesn't generate any html, it generates an absolute url to the resource
 <link href="{{ asset('/css/application.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Well, ok. )  Can you post exactly what does it generetes?

Comment: <link href="https[colon]//dev.site.com/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: What are you talking about? It's part of the blade templating engine. You don't have to put a ; after calls to helper functions and methods when put inside {{ }}

Comment: You had `;` after `.css"` then you edited your comment and `;` dissapeared

Comment: Could have just been a typo I don't remember fixing. Regardless, this doesn't work. No HTTPS request is ever made to fetch the asset

Comment: Hmm. Do you have any plugins like Adblock or Antivirus plugins installed in Firefox?

Comment: I do, but this worked on a previous installation of firefox without those plugins. You bring up a good point though, so I'll try disabling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was very obscure, and I didn't find it until starting Firefox in safe mode. This disabled all addons. When I did that, the page worked fine. The source of the issue was Adblock Plus. After disabling that addon the page works just fine. For some reason Adblock Plus doesn't play well with certain pages over HTTPS, so it may be a bug for them, or the page I was trying to load is being blocked by Adblock (don't know why, it's just a dev machine)

Comment: https[colon]//advertiser.michaell.com/css/application.css is blocked by the following Filter in the EasyList filter that is used in Adblock Plus: /advertiser.$domain=~advertiser.growmobile.com|~panel.rightflow.com

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are using a http protocol for the resources whereas your page is being served with a https protocol as you say.  Match the protocol for the page with the protocol for the resources that you are loading.  e.g. You could use //: rather than http:// or https:// for your resources.

Comment: I guess this is where the fact that this is a laravel app comes in handy
{{ asset('css/application.css') }} is what is used in the href for the CSS. This will generate the proper url, which in this case is: https[colon]//advertiser.michaell.com/css/application.css (dev url)